# C# Discord Bot cmd window closing

Tags: c#, cmd, discord

Having a pretty simple problem but can't seem to find the answer anywhere. I have written a bot for Discord in C#, when debugging, or running from the debug folder everything works as expected. I have now completed all of my functionality, however when I do a release build and run the .exe the command prompt window flashes up and closes again. I understand this is usual behaviour for when the code has finished executing which it would have in this instance. However this is bot waiting for commands, I need the app to keep running and listening for commands.

The code I am using as my program main is:

```
static void Main(string[] args) => new Program().StartAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

I believe the issue must be here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to wrap it in `try .. catch (Exception ex) {Console.WriteLine(ex);}` and do `Console.ReadLine()` at the end so your program waits for Enter key.

Comment: You need to introduce a loop that will run with some sort of exit condition. Like a `quit` command. The loop could be checking that a `quitRequested` boolean remains false, and have the `quit` command set `quitRequested` to true.

Comment: @xmedeko That will only keep the console window open. It will not keep running the app and continue listening for commands.

Comment: I believe this would stop the bot from functioning completely. It is listening for a command via Discord web sockets, nothing ever gets typed into console

Comment: @LewsTherin I will give that a go

Answer (score 1):

You should encapsulate the code in your `Main()` method in a loop that waits for some form of `quit` command from Discord. Something like:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{  
    bool quitRequested = false;

    while (!quitRequested)
    {
        // In your program you need it to receive a "quit" command from discord and
        // return a bool that is set to "true" when the "quit" command is received.
        quitRequested = new Program().StartAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```